# What causes trees to june drop a main branch?

Tags: trees

The other day we had a tree June drop a main branch during a calm period on a windy day (I was in the yard at the time, and it probably would've fallen the other direction had there been some wind at the time). Why would a tree June drop a main branch (the tallest one) at the top of it?

Comment: I don't understand your question; June-drop as opposed to December-drop, versus in any other month? A branch dies, living cells wall it off and the rot begins as the dead branch is invaded by fungi. Eventually it is not mechanically strong enough to remain - it breaks and falls to the ground.

Comment: the top of the tree was green with a lot of new growth, and no fungus was visible.

Comment: @blackthumb can you include a picture at all?  I suspect the branch (perhaps due to overladen fruit) was not strong enough to hold up

Comment: it wasn't a fruit tree.

Comment: Because it broke in June as opposed to any other of 11 months. Branches fall when mechanical failure renders them unable to carry their weight. Fruit trees, because the fruit weight exceeded the branch strength. Water's darn heavy.

Comment: @FiascoLabs so if the top half of a tree falls over, and there's plenty of other leaves that's only due to the weight when there's no wind at the time? sounds odd to me.

Comment: It had a defect of some sort, how heavy were the preceeding winds? I've seen it happen with Sweet Gum trees, wouldn't have the things on my property.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Confusion of terminology; June drop refers specifically to fruits voluntarily dropping from a fruit tree during the month of June, and is not a term used for anything else.

If a branch has fallen from your tree, then that branch has either died, or there was a problem where it was attached to the rest of the tree causing it to drop off. You should be able to tell if the whole branch was dead simply by looking at it, but you might want to check the tree itself thoroughly, just to make sure the rest of it is healthy, because the loss of this branch might indicate a problem.

Comment: It was as green as healthy grass, no fungi and no bugs were in it..

Comment: So not a woody branch then, if it was green? Any evidence at the base to suggest why its fallen?

Comment: it was the main branch about 6 inches in diameter

Comment: But you said it was as green as grass...

Comment: Metaphor - There wasn't a single dead branch on the main branch